# Unable to start the server in Django after including polls.urls in mysite/urls.py

Tags: python, django, linux

I was creating my first view [using this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) in Django I have included all the codes mentioned. I included the below code in ~/testsite/polls/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And I added the line in ~/testsite/testsite/urls.py

```
path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),/home/neonreddeye/testsite/polls"""te>
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please se>    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

When I start the server in linux using

```
$ python3 manage.py runserver
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 438, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 77, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 448, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 634, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 627, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 983, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 913, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/neonreddeye/testsite/testsite/urls.py", line 1
    /home/neonreddeye/testsite/polls"""testsite URL Configuration
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What Do I Do to fix this?

Comment: Have you posted full code of testsite `urls.py` file ? If not edit question and add whole `code`.

Comment: I edited it. take a look.

Comment: The first line of your `urls.py` is causing error remove that line then run server

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first line in testsite/urls.py

path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),/home/neonreddeye/testsite/polls"""te>

Answer (score 0):

That's causing the error you have `syntax` error. Your `path()` must be inside `urlpatterns[]` which you already have so remove that part as

```
"""
The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please se>    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```